# Draw multiple images on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to input some images and draw them in a canvas. I've wrote the following code but, after a lot of searches on the internet, it still draw the last photo inserted.

Please help me. I know that there are some questions related to this one but they really can't help me.

```js
function loadImage() {
  var input, file, img, fr;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 500;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
    write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
    return;
  }

  input = document.getElementById('imgfile');
  if (!input) {
    write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
  } else if (!input.files) {
    write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
  } else if (!input.files[0]) {
    write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      (function(n) {
        setupReader(input.files[n]);

      })(i);
    }

    function setupReader(file) {


      fr = new FileReader();

      addLoadEventFR(createImage);

      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function createImage() {
      img = new Image();
      addLoadEventIMG(imageLoaded);
      img.src = fr.result;
    }

    function imageLoaded() {
      console.log(i);

      ctx.drawImage(img, i * 100, 0);
    }
  }


  function write(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

  function addLoadEventFR(func) {
    var oldonload = fr.onload;
    if (typeof fr.onload != 'function') {
      fr.onload = func;
    } else {
      fr.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
          oldonload();
        }
        func();
      }
    }
  }

  function addLoadEventIMG(func) {
    var oldonload = img.onload;
    if (typeof img.onload != 'function') {
      img.onload = func;
    } else {
      img.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
          oldonload();
        }
        func();
      }
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<input type ='file'  id ='imgfile' multiple></in>
<input type = 'button' class="button" id = 'btnLoad' value="Load" onclick="loadImage()">

<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because on every input selection you are creating a new canvsa element inside `loadImage` function. Initialize canvas once globally and use the same context for drawing images.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function loadImage() {
  var input, file, img, fr;
  if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
    write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
    return;
  }

  input = document.getElementById('imgfile');
  if (!input) {
    write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
  } else if (!input.files) {
    write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
  } else if (!input.files[0]) {
    write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      (function(n) {
        setupReader(input.files[n]);

      })(i);
    }

    function setupReader(file) {
      fr = new FileReader();

      addLoadEventFR(createImage);

      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function createImage() {
      img = new Image();
      addLoadEventIMG(imageLoaded);
      img.src = fr.result;
    }

    function imageLoaded() {
      console.log(i);
      ctx.drawImage(img, i * 100, 0);
    }
  }


  function write(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }

  function addLoadEventFR(func) {
    var oldonload = fr.onload;
    if (typeof fr.onload != 'function') {
      fr.onload = func;
    } else {
      fr.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
          oldonload();
        }
        func();
      }
    }
  }

  function addLoadEventIMG(func) {
    var oldonload = img.onload;
    if (typeof img.onload != 'function') {
      img.onload = func;
    } else {
      img.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
          oldonload();
        }
        func();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type ='file'  id ='imgfile' multiple>
<input type = 'button' class="button" id = 'btnLoad' value="Load" onclick="loadImage()"><br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```